# how i access textbox inside a listview Column

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, listview, c#-4.0

i have a list view like this .

```
<ListView x:Name="Source_List"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectionChanged="Source_List_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Line"
                            Width="50"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LineNumber}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Start Time"
                            Width="100"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartTime , Converter={StaticResource LineTimeToString}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="End Time"
                            Width="100"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndTime ,Converter={StaticResource LineTimeToString}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Text"
                            Width="500">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Context ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Original Text"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Context ,Mode=OneTime}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want to access the text box inside the  selected items as a textbox.(in code behind )
how can i do this?

i used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/09/15/editing-tabular-data-in-wpf-building-a-wpf-grid.aspx) article by beth massi.

Comment: how do you want to access the textbox? in code or in XAML? you should provide more info on that, such as your purpose of doing so...

Answer (score 1):

you can acces to  textbox ui element (if your texblock is clicked)

```
     TextBlock content = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource) as TextBlock;
```

else if your texblock is inside a grid use

```
      Grid c = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource) as Grid;
```

and search for the grid(c) children.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` you should be able to access the current item of your list `'Lines'`. Your text box is bound to Context so I would assume in your view model you would be able to call `'Lines.CurrentItem.Context'`

Comment: i want to access that text box as TextBox object like normal textbox. Context (in my Line Object is a string) . pleas help me

Comment: for what purpose exactly? because you shouldn't couple your view with your view model however in the xaml.cs if you gave your textbox a name or an x:name then you would be able to access it there.

Comment: Ok . Thanks for answer .